# OS X Delegate set label from other window (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, delegates

I'm quite new to Mac programming (not to Objective C).

I'm developing a small application, that shows some data and opens a second window on button press.
In the second window is a textfield and a submit button. If the submit button is pressed, the window should close + the value of the textfield needs to be passed to the first window.

I think the best method for that is a simple Delegate. I tried that but i can't change the label in the first window using the second window..
The delegate however seems to work as i can call methods from the other class and send data to it. It just won't change the label.

As this is my first try on Delegates, im pretty sure I've done something stupid here^^

or is there a better solution? Can't be to complicated to change a label from an second window.. right?

**ViewController.h (FirstController)**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class ViewController;

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate
    -(void)sayHello:(ViewController *)ViewController;
@end

@interface ViewController : NSViewController
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txtlabel;
}
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;
    -(void)helloDelegate;
    -(void)reciveVar:(NSString*)strvar;

@end
```

**ViewController.m (FirstController)**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize delegate;

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];

    return self;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    txtlabel.stringValue=@"TEST";
}


-(void)helloDelegate
{
    [delegate sayHello:self];
}

-(void)reciveVar:(NSString*)strvar
{
    NSLog(@"recived: %@", strvar);
    txtlabel.stringValue=strvar; // DOSENT WORK!!
}

@end
```

**secondController.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface secondController : NSViewController <ViewControllerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *txtfield;
}

 -(IBAction)submit:(id)sender;

@end
```

**secondController.m**

```
#import "firstController.h"

@implementation secondController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ViewController *custom = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    // assign delegate
    custom.delegate = self;
    [custom helloDelegate];
}

-(void)sayHello:(ViewController *)ViewController
{
    NSLog(@"Hiya!");
}

-(IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    NSString *txtval= txtfield.stringValue;
    NSLog(@"submit: %@", txtval);

    ViewController *custom = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    // assign delegate
    custom.delegate = self;
    [custom reciveVar:txtval];
}



@end
```

**LOG Output:**

1. Hiya!
2. submit: test
3. recived: test

(so i guess the delegate works..)

Comment: Two things....  You seem to have the delegation backwards.  I think you want `ViewController` to take action when `secondController` requests it.  Much more important, though, is that `ViewController *custom = [[ViewController alloc] init];` creates a **new** object.  What you do to it has no effect on the `ViewController` that already exists.

Comment: makes sense.. any idea how i can get access to the existing ViewController?

Comment: You say the second window opens on a button press.  If that's handled by `ViewController` or something that has a reference to `ViewController`, it can pass `self` or the reference as something like `controller2.delegate = ...;`.  Otherwise, it really depends on the app's structure.

Comment: If sharing references isn't an available option, you can always switch to `NSNotification` instead of delegate as a strategy.

Comment: It's just another view controller connected with the button of the 1. view controller through a sheet segue.. I actually tried passing self.. didn't work.. but i'll give it another try.

Thanks for the suggestion of NSNotification.. i shortly looked into this.. afaic this only stores the value but does not pass it to the other window.. Meaning i would need another button in firstController to load it into the label right?

Comment: When you send a notification you can attach information to it either as the notification object or in the userinfo dictionary.  So the listener (first controller) can be given whatever you like.

Comment: NSNotification works perfekt! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED. (Thanks to  [Phillip Mills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784753/phillip-mills))

NSNotification is way simpler and efficient than Delegates in this case.

**ViewController.m**

```
[...]

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    txtlabel.stringValue=@"TEST";
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleUpdatedData:)
                                                 name:@"DataUpdated"
                                               object:nil];
}
-(void)handleUpdatedData:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"recieved %@", notification);
    txtlabel.stringValue=[notification object];
}
```

**secondController.m**

```
-(IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    NSString *txtval= txtfield.stringValue;
    NSLog(@"submit: %@", txtval);


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DataUpdated"
                                                        object:txtval];
}
```